# p-adic Eisenstein series

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I'm trying to understand the basic properties of the p-adic Eisenstein series.

Let $p$ be a prime number.

Define the group $X = 
\begin{cases} 
\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}  & \mbox{if }p \neq2 \\
\mathbb{Z}_2 & \mbox{if } p=2
\end{cases}$

where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers.

If $k\in X$ and $d$ is a positive integer then is it true that $d^{k-1}\in \mathbb{Z}_p$? If so, why?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like your previous question, there's a slight philosophical issue: the question should not be "is $d^{k-1} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$", but "when and how is $d^{k-1}$ defined"? It's far from obvious what the definition should be, but once you know what the conventional definition is, the fact that it gives you something in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ whenever it is defined is totally obvious :-)

So we have to do something to define $d^{x}$ for $x \in X$, and it will only work if $d \in \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. The usual definition is as follows. Let me assume $p \ne 2$ -- you can work out the necessary modifications for $p = 2$ yourself.

Suppose $x = (x_1, x_2)$ where $x_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $x_2 \in \mathbb{Z} / (p-1)\mathbb{Z}$. Write $d = \langle d \rangle \tau(d)$, where $\tau(d)$ is a $(p-1)$-st root of unity and $\langle d \rangle$ is in $1 + p\mathbb{Z}_p$ (this can always be done, in a unique way, for any $d \in \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$). Then we define
$$ d^x = \langle d \rangle^{x_1} \tau(d)^{x_2} $$
which is well-defined (using [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436984/raising-a-rational-integer-to-a-p-adic-power)) and lies in $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. It's easy to check that this agrees with the "natural" definition of $d^x$ when $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ (which lives inside $X$ in the obvious way). In fact $X$ is exactly the set of group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times \to \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$.

If $k \in X$ we can now define $d^{k-1} = d^k / d$, where $d^k$ is defined as above.

There's no sensible definition of $d^x$ for $x \in X$ and $d \in p\mathbb{Z}$, which is why the definition of the coefficient of $q^n$ in the $p$-adic Eisenstein series involves a sum over only those divisors of $n$ coprime to $p$.

Comment: I have a few questions-- so would the natural embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $X$ be given by $x\mapsto (x,0)$? Then by your answer to my subsequent question, would it be more accurate to say that $d^x$ being defined for all $x\in X$ implies that $d\in 1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$?    (2) In the decomposition for $d$ should there be an additional factor equal to a power of the prime element $p$ generating the maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_p$?  (3) Is there an easy way of seeing that $X$ is the set of group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_p\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{\times}_p$?

Comment: (4) As you say, for the $p$-adic Eisenstein series, the sum defining the coefficient of $q^n$ is taken over all divisors $d$ of $n$ coprime to $p$. Wouldn't this involve integers which are not congruent to 1 mod$(p)$, therefore we wouldn't be able to raise them to the power $k-1$?    Thank you very much.

Comment: Please ignore my second question- you're right of course since $d\in \mathbb{Z}_p- p\mathbb{Z}_p$ so $v_p(d)=0$.

Comment: The natural embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $X$ is given by $n \mapsto (n, n \bmod{p-1})$.

Comment: Your questions (1) and (4) suggest you are labouring under a misunderstanding. The definition of $d^x$ for $x \in X$ makes sense when $d \in \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$, and this definition is different from the definition of $d^y$ for $y \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, which only makes sense when $d \in 1 + p\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: So if $d\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ then is $d\in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ a necessary and sufficient condition for $d^x$ to be well-defined for all $x\in X$?

Comment: Again there is this philosophical issue: definitions are a human construct: they are what we want them to be. I could define $d^x$ to be $0$ (for all $x \in X$) if $d \in p\mathbb{Z}_p$ and that would be perfectly well-defined.

Comment: Sorry, I meant whether $d\in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $d^x$ to lie in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for all $x\in X$.    The reason why asked question (1) above was because I thought that if $d^x\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ for all $x\in X$ then in particular this is true for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ (since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is contained in $X$), thus implying that $d\in 1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$. Sorry for labouring this point but I'm a bit confused owing to my limited mathematical knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: StackExchange doesn't encourage long-winded debates in comments. I see from your profile that you're an undergraduate in London. There are dozens of people in London who work with this stuff every day; go and talk to one of them.